# Julia - How do I add a matrix to a list of matrices

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, append, julia, push

I'm new to Julia, and I am currently working on a model where I need to add a matrix to list of matrices. I am trying to accomplish this with:

```
push!(BranchDomainNew, BranchDomain[k])
```

Where `BranchDomainNew` is a 1x7 matrix (3D) made up of matrices. I am trying to append `BranchDomain[k]` (another matrix of the same dimensions) to this list. Ultimately, my goal is to have `BranchDomainNew` be 8 matrices long, with the last index containing `BranchDomain[k]`.

Here's the error I keep getting:

```
MethodError: no method matching push!(::Matrix{Any}, ::Matrix{Bool})
```

I also tried using `append!()`, which unfortunately also did not work - I got the same error (except `append!` instead of `push!`). I'd love to know why these methods don't work for this, and how I can accomplish this goal. Also, I am working with version v"1.7.2". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `push!` or `append!` elements to a matrix, because matrices are 2-dimensional entities, and adding single elements could ruin its shape, and is therefore not allowed. You can instead concatenate rows or columns using `hcat` or `vcat`.

But it looks like what you really should use is a `Vector`, not a 1xN `Matrix`.

So make sure that `BranchDomainNew` is a `Vector` of matrices, instead of a `Matrix` of matrices. Then you can `push!` and `append!` all you like.

You did not show how you made your matrix, but it is possible that you did something like this:

```
BranchDomainNew = [mat1 mat2 mat3]  # create 1x3 Matrix
```

when you should have done

```
BranchDomainNew = [mat1, mat2, mat3]  # create length 3 Vector
```

It is a common mistake for many new Julia users to use 1xN or Nx1 matrices, when they should actually use a length-N vector. For example, they often initialize arrays as `zeros(N, 1)`, when they should use `zeros(N)`

The difference is important, and in almost all cases a vector is better.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. Initializing BranchDomainNew as a vector rather than a 3D matrix solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as 'accepted'.